# Submitting multiple forms from a single view

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Using CakePHP I have a page where I have multiple forms. Each form updates a single field on a record. I'm trying to implement a way to submit all the forms through a single "Submit All" button. However, all my solutions so far have been lest than successful.

My first attempt was to create a separate action called `editAll` in the controller that took an array, but I cannot figure out how to send the data from all the forms to that action without having a hidden form that saves all that data. The second idea was to create some kind of Javascript function that iterated over all the forms to create an array to be sent to the controller's `editAll` action.

The first implementation did not work, and I couldn't find a reasonable way to implement the second idea.

Basically, I was hoping someone could point me in the direction to submitting multiple forms (or at least the data from multiple forms) at once from a single page.

Comment: If you want all the data to be submitted together why are you using multiple forms?

Comment: As ADmad says; create a single form, but split/process the posted data server-side if required

Comment: Well, I don't always want to submit all the data every time. It seems splitting the data on the server may be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't ALWAYS want to submit them all - if you do, then just make one form. If you're hoping to be able to submit some of them individually, but also be able to submit them all, then you could do something along the lines of this:

Keep all the fields in one form.  For each field have a 'submitted' value (1 or 0).  If they click the Submit next to an individual field, turn all of the submitted values to 0 except that one, then submit the form.

If they click Submit All, then turn them all to '1' and submit the form.

Then, when you process the data, just strip anything that doesn't have 'submitted' value of 1.

It would still take some work, and you're submitting more data than is necessary, but.... it's an idea.

Comment: This seems to be where everyone has been pointing me to. Thanks for the help.